# powershell from chef resource powershell_script

Tags: powershell, chef-infra

I am trying to use one var declared outside chef resource  powershell_script.
    cn_name = `powershell.exe  hostname`
    puts cn_name ## will print like WIN-I5NP98N6JUE.cpteam.local 
Now , i am trying to get the thumbprint of the root CA cert installed in this host.

```
powershell_script 'import CA_cert' do
    code <<-EOH
    $Thumbprint = (Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\\LocalMachine\\Root | Where-Object {$_.Subject -match "CN="#{cn_name}""}).Thumbprint;
    EOH
end
This is printing like : + ... ct -match "CN="WIN-I5NP98N6JUEcpteam.local""}).Thumbprint;
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'WIN-I5NP98N6JUEcpteam.local""' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Kindly help me here how to escape those quotes./ before quotes doesnt work.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That should be `{$_.Subject -match "CN=#{cn_name}"})`, you don't need the extra quotes at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.In that case, it is not at all printing the variable. If i print it inside the chef powershell resource it prints correctly with CN="#{cn_name}" . Just when I use it in that line, it goofs up with those 2 quotes.

Answer (score 0):

try this to escape your extra quotes:

`` $Thumbprint = (Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\\LocalMachine\\Root | Where-Object {$_.Subject -match "CN=`"#{cn_name}`""}).Thumbprint; ``